# This Image was hotlinked

Tags: wordpress, multisite, hotlinking

I am working on wordpress multisite. I have Total 4 Sites.Only Main site is working good. In other 3 sites I am facing issue for images - **"This image was hotlinked"** 
[image]

Comment: Assuming for the sake of `until proven guilty` that you are authorized to hotlink the images, what kind of protection is used? I think you have to somewhat exclude your domains or include them in some sort of whitelist

Comment: @salvatore How do I include them in whitelist ??

Comment: I need to know the pretection that you are using to tell you for sure, if it's `.htaccess` based, you have to add a few lines to allow your websites.

Comment: @salvatore I have already tried and add all possible code in .htaccess file, but nothing works. Any other solution than .htaccess ??

Comment: Can you add the contents of .htaccess file to your question? replace sensitive information with # if needed

Comment: When I **Inspect**  original image is there, When I open Image Link in new tab **hotlinked** image is display and then when I refresh Image Link page original image is display. But still in whole site **hotlinked** images are displayed.

Comment: Also when I re-upload image from back-end , it is still showing **hotlinked** in back-end and in front-end.

Comment: Maybe the `.htaccess` is messed up, but i think it's just that whoever wrote it didn't take into account the multisite installation

Comment: If you set to rewrite all images not coming from domain1 to the placeholder, but then you open the site using the domain2, it will obviously rewrite all the images, because domain2 is not domain1, even if you are in the admin panel

Answer (score 0):

*It's difficult to give an answer based on so many assumptions, but i'll try.*

Assuming that:

- You use apache as the webserver
- You have 3 different domains that point to the same directory on the same server
- You don't have a CDN that may interfere
- You don't have installed WP plugins to protect against hotlinking
- You use the `.htaccess` file to protect against hotlinking
- You've edited you `.htaccess` adding something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?yourdomain.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?google.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?bing.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?yahoo.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg)$ http://yourdomain.com/hotlink-placeholder.jpg [NC,R,L]
```

**THEN**

You have to add the other domains thet need to access to the images, consider the `RewriteCond` list as an exclusion list, that says "*Apply the rewrite rule only when the referer is not in this list*", so you have to add the other domains to the list.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?yourdomain.com [NC]
#this
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?yourdomain2.com [NC]
#and this
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?yourdomain3.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?google.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?bing.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?yahoo.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg)$ http://yourdomain.com/hotlink-placeholder.jpg [NC,R,L]
```

If you can't make the `.htaccess` to work properly, consider switching to a plugin, they will manage the file for you

If you need some tool to check you `.htaccess` changes before submitting them, take a look at [this](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/)

Comment: Yes I write above code in .htaccess , but i wite it only for one domain name. Well I am bit worried to write it for all domain because  one site is working good with all images from all that four sites.

Comment: Make a backup of your actual `.htaccess` file that works, and restore it if somethings doesn't work (_this is actually a good practice_). I've edited the answer to give you a tool you can use to check the behaviour of the `.htaccess` file, just remember to try the differente referrers